# How to customize NSMenu like the Apple Pro Apps?

Tags: cocoa, customization, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I want to customize a `NSMenu` with `NSMenuItems`, so does it looks like the Apple Pro Apps.

But how can I customize a `NSMenu`? There is no draw method to change the appearance. 
If I set a `NSView` to a `NSMenuItem`, I can set the background color, but I will loose highlighting and menu handling. Furthermore the top and bottom cap of the `NSMenu` cannot be customized.

I found only [this hint](http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2009-06/msg00426.html), but unfortunately without code.

[image: Dark TableView with a white menu and white menu items]

I would be very happy for some help!

Comment: Did you successfully customize the NSMenu?

Comment: I found the [sources of NSMenu and others](http://sid.ethz.ch/debian/gnustep/gnustep-gui-0.20.0/Source/). Though, I could not find a useful hint there.

Comment: I wonder if it would be helpful to get the `MenuRef` with `_NSGetCarbonMenu()` as mentioned [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064386/reverse-engineering-an-nsmenu-for-a-status-bar-item).

Comment: There is no solution for this.

Comment: Care to post a screenshot illustrating what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JJD the sources you have found are for GNUStep - developed entirely independently to Apple's Cocoa, albeit aiming to implement the same api (well, aiming at some combo of OpenStep/modern Cocoa). It can be instructive to consider the GNUStep sources, but keep in mind undocumented cases, or even documented cases, may well behave differently.

Comment: There is a private method `_setHasPadding:onEdge:` that can be used to remove the top and bottom caps.

Answer (score 2):

The hard answer is, make your own, subclass NSMenu, NSMenuItem etc and manually handle the drawing, animations etc.