# NSMenuItem custom view problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I am trying to put a custom view inside an NSMenuItem and this is result I get:

[image]

How can I remove the white padding on top and on the right hand side?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, should have looked better before asking. For those wondering, it was answered here:
[Gap above NSMenuItem custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533816/gap-above-nsmenuitem-custom-view)