# NSView drawRect interfering with subviews?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, drawrect, nsbutton

I have an nsview and i use draw rect to draw an image for background. It also has 3 subviews nsbuttons. The problem is, whenever the mouse is down on a button, the other buttons disappear. But when I remove the draw rect method, this doesn't happen. So I am guessing this has to do with the draw rect method for drawing images.

How can I avoid this?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok, i figured out where the problem is. Basically, I have an NSMenuItem, and I am putting a view inside it with 3 buttons. But in NSMenu, at the top, there's a padding of 4 pixels. So, basically, to remove that padding I used the solution provided here: 
[Gap above NSMenuItem custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533816/gap-above-nsmenuitem-custom-view)

From the solution there's a line in the drawRect method:

```
[[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:fullBounds] setClip];
```

The moment, i remove this line, and the button behave properly. But then, the padding on top doesn't go away.

Here's my drawRect:

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] saveGraphicsState];

    NSRect fullBounds = [self bounds];
    fullBounds.size.height += 4;
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:fullBounds] setClip];

    NSImage *background = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    [background drawInRect:fullBounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:100.0];

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Comment: Could you post your custom `drawRect:`?

Comment: Posted the drawRect method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the linked question doesn't include saving and restoring the graphics state, which is a good idea when you are modifying one that you didn't create. Give this a try:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   // Save the current clip rect that has been set up for you
   [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
   // Calculate your fullBounds rect
   // ...
   // Set the clip rect
   // ...
   // Do your drawing
   // ...
   // Restore the correct clip rect
   [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that didn't work. Also, i think you mean saveGraphicsState and restoreGraphicsState? Thanks again.

Comment: @user635064: I did mean that, yes, thanks; I've been making typos all day long. You should still use this even though it doesn't directly address your problem; it will prevent others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those buttons are actually subviews, and not just placed over the view you're drawing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am sure, but, I figured what what's causing the problem expect I don't know how to fix it. Please read my original question again because I edited it and explained the problem in detail. Thanks again.