# Gap is showing in my NSMenuItem custom view in Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, menuitem

I was looking at this post: [Gap above NSMenuItem custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533816/gap-above-nsmenuitem-custom-view) and this seems to be not working in Mac OS X 10.10.

I have a custom MenuItem and MenuItemView classes and prior to 10.10, they are working fine. Now, I can see the gray-colored gap at the top and bottom of the menuitem view. Only seen in Mac OS X 10.10. Is this a Yosemite issue or do I need to handle this?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't targeting Mac App Store, here's a workaround using a **private API** for turning the top padding off.

First, declare the following category on `NSMenu` (otherwise you'll get lots of ARC *unknown-selector*-errors):

```
@interface NSMenu (Private)
// Use NSMaxYEdge to toggle the top padding
// and NSMinYEdge to toggle the bottom one
- (void)_setHasPadding: (BOOL)enabled onEdge: (NSRectEdge) edge;
@end
```

Then use it as follows:

```
[self.menu _setHasPadding: NO onEdge: NSMaxYEdge];
```

Comment: thanks. i can use this for now until such time I can figure out how to do this the proper way. But thanks for your response.

Comment: @jtubog I also encourage you to duplicate [the radar I filed about this issue](http://www.openradar.me/19661956).