# NSMenuItem - Removing Bottom Gap Below Custom View

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, nsmenuitem

I have created several status menu (`NSStatusBar`) applications before.  But I have never done in Swift.  If you set a custom view to a menu item, you will get a 5-point border at the bottom.  I didn't think that's something you could remove.  I didn't know that there's some literature on this topic till today.  One topic is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533816/gap-above-nsmenuitem-custom-view).

Anyway, the following is what I have.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem = NSStatusItem()
    var statusImage = NSImage()

    func showStatusMenu() {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        let img = NSImage.init(named: "StatusImage")
        statusItem.image = img!.resize(w: 18.0, h: 18.0)
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu

        let topMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        let viewRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, 30)
        let menuItemView = TopBackground.init(frame: viewRect)
        menuItemView.autoresizingMask = .viewWidthSizable
        topMenuItem.view = menuItemView
        statusMenu.addItem(topMenuItem)
    }
}

class TopBackground: NSView {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame:frameRect);
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect:NSRect) {
        var fullBounds = self.bounds
        fullBounds.size.height += 4
        NSBezierPath(rect: fullBounds).setClip()
        NSColor.blue.set()
        NSRectFill(fullBounds)
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

[image][image]

Anyway, I cannot remove the gap at the bottom.  What am I doing wrong?

Muchos thankos.

Comment: I don't see a gap. I see a separator menu item.

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm...  A gap will appear if I set the TopBackground subclass to a custom NSView class that is placed at the very bottom of the menu, though.

Comment: Like regular menu items. If you want to add an area to the bottom of the view, you have to move the view. Do something like `fullBounds.origin.y -= 4.0`.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for your tip.  I have actually set the origin -= 4.0 to see what happens.  Anyway, I have updated images above.

Comment: Replace `NSRectFill(rect)` by `NSRectFill(fullBounds)`.

Comment: Oh, shoot...  That's my mistake.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, nothing has changed after correcting the NSRectFill mistake.